# Keycloak Error: could not download chart: Chart.yaml file is missing

Tags: terraform, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, bitnami

I am trying to install keycloak using helm_release resource in terraform, but I get the error - Chart.yaml is missing.
I have tried codecentric and bitnami repository for keycloak.

P.S -> Terraform plan works fine but not terraform apply

```
  resource "helm_release" "keycloak" {
  name       = "keycloak"
  repository = "https://codecentric.github.io/helm-charts"
  version    = "15.0.2"
  chart      = "codecentric/keycloak"
  namespace  = "default"
  values     = ["${file("values.yml")}"]
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `oci://registry-1.docker.io/bitnamicharts/keycloak` for `repository` argument?

Comment: I tried and it says " Error: could not download chart: failed to authorize: failed to fetch anonymous token: unexpected status: 400 Bad Request"

Comment: Uhm, well, there is also a syntax error in the above code. You forgot the closing square bracket here: `["${file("values.yml")}"`.

Comment: Its correct in my code though.. i'll edit here too

Comment: I tried ingress-nginx using https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx" repo it worked,keycloak behaves wierd

Comment: I used both URLs and the plan works. Which version of the Helm provider are you using?

Comment: i realise the helm(v2.9.0) provider by terraform is not able to get this keycloak version .....By normal helm (3.12.0) install commands this is working...Not sure which version of helm provider in terraform will be compatible with this version of keycloak

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it is too late to solve your problem, but I had the same error. The cause of the problem is that the **helm_release** resource should not be placed in the folder with name equals to helm chart.

So in my case renaming of the module (folder) from devlake to devlake_instance was the solution.